# How do I allow a function to use jQuery.i18n?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internationalization

I am having a problem getting my functions to use the jQuery.i18n. It works fine inside `jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {...});`, not outside of it.

```
jQuery(function($) {
  $.i18n().load({
    'en': '/path/to/i18n/en.json'
  });
});

jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    function payInfo('example@something.com', '12341234');

    console.log('Verification text test: ' + $.i18n('payments.verificationCode')); // works
});

function payInfo(address, invoice) {
    // translation does not work here
    swal({
        title: $.i18n('payments.verificationCode'),
        html: $.i18n('payments.verificationDetail', address),
        input: 'number',
        showCancelButton: true,
        confirmButtonText: $.i18n('global.confirm'),
        cancelButtonText: $.i18n('global.cancel'),
        showLoaderOnConfirm: true,
        inputPlaceholder: '0000',
        allowOutsideClick: false
     })
}
```

The error is `TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '$.i18n')` - and points to the `title:` line number. What is the correct way of allowing the function to get the i18n translations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your jQuery  is not globally defined. Try adding this in `.ready`:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    window.$ = $; // This line
    function payInfo('example@something.com', '12341234');

    console.log('Verification text test: ' + $.i18n('payments.verificationCode')); // works
});
```